# HTML5 video - displaying only subsection of a longer video

Tags: javascript, html5-video, fragment

I would like to show only a certain section from a long HTML5 video where the full video will not be accessible at all. I need to have something like this http://metavid.ucsc.edu/wiki/Stream:Senate_proceeding_02-13-09/0:05:40/0:47:29

I know about the option of using Media Fragment URI, but I don't know how exactly show with it only the requested part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Media Fragment URI is a good option and to restrict users from accessing other parts of the video you just need to have your own custom controls. For example -- http://ninsuna.elis.ugent.be/MFPlayer/html5

Here is also a tutorial for building HTML5 video custom controls --- http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1347

Answer (score 1):

Please check the `video` specification.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/video.html#offsets-into-the-media-resource